# Simulate a mouse click in Flash using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

**Background:** I'm developing Greasemonkey scripts for a website. I do not control the Flash file.

**Question:**  Is it possible to simulate a mouse click on a button/movie clip in a Flash object embedded in a web page? Googling only shows ways to simulate a mouse click on a DOM element, and ways that require the ActionScript to be changed to implement a JavaScript interface. Or is this simply impossible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible unless the SWF implements ExternalInterfaces and opens up a function to be called from Javascript to allow it access to the _root.  Even then, the SWF has to have methods inside it to allow calling onclick events.  The best you can do is clicking on the object element because Javascript doesn't have a method for simulating a click at a specific (x, y)

Comment: Nope, not without control of the SWF.