# IPAD : How to play video in fullscreen without User Action

Tags: ios, ipad, video, fullscreen

I load html5 / youtube and DMcloud video in a UIWebview on my IPAD with :

```
[adView loadHTMLString:script baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
```

I want to launch this in fullscreen same with an iphone in fullscreen with controls.
I read more topic. It's may be not possible !

I test with :
 edit :    `adView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;`

```
     mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

but don't works !
I don't want a simple resize but really a full screen.

It's possible without User Action ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the property `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` of `webview` set to NO.

```
adView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Check these links for more help [How to autoplay a YouTube video in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/objective-c-how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview) and  [Youtube video autoplay inside UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385791/youtube-video-autoplay-inside-uiwebview)

Comment: it's not the autoplay what I really want. I already manage autoplay. It's the full screen what I want because actually my video is playing in the webview. When the video is in the fullscreen, You can already watch the video if the webview is close/destroy. Not in the first case.